# Disabling INSERT operations on Default Value Columns - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, constraints

In Sql Server 2008, I have a table that is filled by a data provider application.

I want to keep an "**INSERT_DATE**" column on table, so that I can know the date the record is inserted.

In order to do this, I defined a default constraint on **INSERT_DATE** column which puts GETDATE() by default.

However, I don't want this column value to be overwritten by data provider application.

So, how can I disable insert into **INSERT_DATE** column?

(I cannot use computed column. Because Clustered Index uses INSERT_DATE field)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an After Insert [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). That way, whatever is inserted into that column for an inserted row you could update to the current date/time.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want the column updates as well when the row is subsequently updated.

Your best bet is to use a `trigger`. You might not be able to throw an error if the application provides a value but at least you will be able to set it right by skipping the column in the insert you specify in your trigger.